# How to get a list of all the commands available for Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line

I want to start using the terminal more often, but I don't know what are the different commands available to me. Is there a way to list all the different commands that I can make use of?

Answer (score 30):

### First Method

**NB**: Thanks to @Rmano. This method doesn't work with  `zsh` shell.

A simple command:

```
ls ${PATH//:/ }
```

This will list all commands in your `$PATH` environment variable.

To store the result in a file you can redirect the output to a file.

```
ls ${PATH//:/ } > mycommands.txt
```

Note that this will return an error if any directory names in your `$PATH` contain spaces. In that case, use this instead:

```
while read -d ':' dir; do echo "$dir"; done <<<$PATH
```

### Second Method

Also you can use:

```
compgen -c | sort -u > commands && less commands
```

### Third Method

Another method is a double <kbd>Tab</kbd> click.

### Fourth Method

Another method using `find` command:

```
find {,/usr}/{,s}bin -printf '%f\n\0'
```

Comment: Notice that the first command works in `bash` but not in `zsh`, which has word split disabled by default. http://www.refining-linux.org/archives/38/ZSH-Gem-3-No-automatic-word-split/

Answer (score 12):

If you are using bash, which is the default shell in all official Ubuntu flavors, run `compgen -c` to see the available commands including aliases.

Comment: Is that bash only?

Comment: Even the commands for gui-based programs are included. So if you do `compgen -c | grep thunar` and you have the Thunar file manager installed, you'll see commands related to Thunar as well.

Comment: Mmm... is doesn't work in Debian. Which package provides that?

Comment: works on Ubuntu server @Braiam Oh and it is a bash builtin. see: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Programmable-Completion-Builtins

Comment: @Rinzwind that explains it, I'm using zsh.

Comment: @vasa1: Could this answer be more general? I mean it only provides the solution for bash, but as Braiam noted it doesn't work for zsh... If possible could you please expand the answer to cater to a larger audience - obviously only if you know the answer :-)

Comment: @Aditya, no, I don't know about other shells. Bash, I understand, is the default shell in all official Ubuntu flavors.

Comment: -1 because this is not standard: it's a bash built-in and may not function with other common shells nor be usable with other bash forks. I suggest to enhance your post with the syntax for a bash alias.

Comment: @lorenzo if Ubuntu + bash is OUR standard this answer is perfectly valid.

Comment: @Rinzwind the "Ubuntu + bash" combination isn't a common standard and we can't (yet :) ) make our international standards; not all Ubuntu & Debian based systems must use any particular version of bash or of the bash scripting language: they can use dash, the korn shell etc. as default user shell. Also, remember that bash will not respect the POSIX standard by default and, for that, it is a replaceable interface to the system. The bash builtins - sadly - are not part of any standard, as I told: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29#Portability  Have a nice day.

Comment: Why are you fighting?  For zsh, it's just `bash -c -- "compgen -c"`

Answer (score 4):

Open terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> and run this command:

```
whatis `compgen -c` | more
```

This will list all commands and a simple description of each command.

If you want to save the list you can redirect the result into an output file

```
whatis `compgen -c` > listOfCommands.txt
```

So why I used whatis command. The command
`man whatis` gives:

> Each manual page has a short description available within  it.
>   whatis
>          searches  the  manual  page names and displays the manual page descrip‐
>          tions of any name matched.

so in easy words `whatis` give a general. description of each command

Comment: +1 for additional info. **whatis \`compgen -c\` | sort > listOfCommands.txt** will help go get in sort list.

Comment: Another useful command: `apropos <keyword>` searches all commands and their short description and displays the results

Answer (score 3):

Open up a terminal and press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key twice.

Comment: -1 because this is not standard.

Comment: @LorenzoAncora why is it not standard? Does not all Ubuntu have the autocompletion with double Tab as standard behaviour?

Comment: Default != standard: in a future maybe we'll have a console that does not support that mechanism, because it's not standard; more, the TAB standard may serve a different function. A standard procedure is listing the content of 'bin', because is part of the official FHS standard and any Linux/Unix system has that directory. The correct functionality (and the ability of the community to help the users) of Ubuntu is ensured by the respect of the standards.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation :) I thought that the standard behaviout of the double Tab on Ubuntu was to list the content of PATH :)

Comment: @LorenzoAncora Listing the contents of any one directory will not show anywhere close to all executable commands. Listing the contents of *all* PATH directories will not show shell builtins with no corresponding executable (such as `cd`). Pressing Tab twice overcomes both these severe limitations. If someone had asked how to show all commands on an arbitrary GNU/Linux system, one might argue that Tab completion is not an adequate solution. Of course *anything* might change in Ubuntu in the future but the likelihood of tab completion in the default interactive shell going away is minuscule.

Comment: For Eliah Kagan: Learning the build-ins (which are reduced versions of external utility) is part of knowing the shell, use the internal help for that.
For dadexix: Enviroment variables, like PATH, can be altered and the listing of their content may vary from shell to shell, it's not a standard like the filesystem hierarchy. The default shell may vary.
For both: I'm not here for useless philosophical disputes: in my opinion, if you don't know what shell the user is going to use, give a well documented and safe answer. Who knows the future? :-)

Answer (score 2):

A list of command depends greatly on what you have installed, but there are cheats to list all commands. The following works on most bourne-like shells:

1. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice.
2. Use `find` to find all executables:

   ```
   find / -perm +x
   ```
3. List all the files in the binaries directories (could be incomplete):

   ```
   ls /bin /sbin /usr/bin /usr/sbin /usr/local/bin /usr/local/sbin
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal window (GNOME terminal is OK, also a configured xTerm).
Your options are:

- **By pressing the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key ("-><-") twice, you'll complete any command in the console and, if the line is empty, you'll get the number and the names of all available commands**. Please note that it may require some time and may list semi-administrative utilities.
  NOTE: this isn't a standard, for a "cross-shell" way see the other options.
- **Use `man -k NAME` to search for a command** (or part of it) and `man COMMAND` to obtain the manual for that command. Not al commands have a system manual; reading the man **before** using any administrative utility is always a good idea; trust me.
- Use Midnight Commander (`mc`) to have a nice console (curses) GUI to manage the system and the file system. You may have to install it from your package manager. Don't worry; it is safe and extremely common software.
  NOTE: It's made for when you have confusion or difficulty in using the file system.
- Use `ls /bin | more` to know all **exential administrative executables**; `ls /sbin | more` for **common administrative executables**.
- Use `ls /usr/sbin | more` to know all **user executables**; `ls /usr/sbin | more` will give a very huge list of **user executables and libraries**.
  NOTE: If the output from `more` exceeds one page (screenful), you'll have to scroll py pressing "Page Up" and "Page Down" or spacebar.
  You can use `COMMAND | grep TEXT` to filter the output.

If you have more questions comment under here and don't forget to check the tick next to the answer if I helped you.
Have a nice experience.

Comment: Usually, most executables are in `/usr/bin`, which you haven't mentioned here. Also there's `/sbin`, which contains executables often used for system administration, such as `usermod` and `ifconfig`. And many systems have other binary directories as well, like `/usr/games` and `/usr/local/bin`. See [Filesystem hierarchy standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_hierarchy_standard) and [`man 7 hier`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man7/hier.7.html). You might want to expand this to mention important directories for executables besides `/bin` and `/usr/sbin`.

Answer (score -1):

This is a bit old, but can be still relevant

http://fosswire.com/post/2008/04/ubuntu-cheat-sheet/

And information on using the Ubuntu terminal

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal

the above page has more links at the end which will help you finding more commands for Ubuntu.