# Can bash "complete" command change so far typed input?

Tags: command-line, auto-completion

I'd like to write a dynamic completion script that modifies the so far typed command.

For example if I type:

```
$ myapp give me a random command<tab><tab>
```

- completion function would call REST endpoint with "give me a random command" payload
- endpoint would return "ls -al" (so far I'm good)
- complete would replace "myapp give me a random command" with "ls -al" (I need help only with this step).

```
$ ls -al
```

I don't know if it is even possible with `complete` command.
If it is possible I need a clue how to do that, if it is not possible with `complete` is there any other approach I could take?

Comment: overide tab key in custom keys, to run a script, to set a count of how many tabs pressed in a certain time frame. if one tab and say .5 second delay , pass on to normal completion (I am not sure about how to do that one)... if two tabs, run your script to randomly select from a list of commands. might be better to forget the tabs and make it for just running a random command script. and when I say run command at the end, I mean paste the text  as in run xdotool to run ctl-shift-v (konsole) to paste in the random command. which you could just do with a hotkey that is not a tab    -

Comment: keys defined here 
   /usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h

all commands available.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/403435/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-the-commands-available-for-ubuntu

Comment: keys defined here 
   /usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h

all commands available.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/403435/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-the-commands-available-for-ubuntu

echo "whatever random  command " | xsel -ib && xsel -ob'

and add the paste command keys, ctrl-shist-v, with xdotool

Comment: @pierrely thank you for your input! 
I decided to take a little bit different approach (bash function + xdotool) https://github.com/jkatnik/ai-bash

Answer (score 0):

I changed my "requirements" and combined bash function with xdotool